# Drag & Drop (swap) 3 texture buttons in a Margin Container->VBox

Tags: godot, gdscript

Following along a great tutorial, code is replicated yet does not function as shown. No new texture appears to be created when I try to drag the texture button. Only difference is the tutorial uses a TextureRect, while I'm using a TextureButton.

```
extends TextureButton


func get_drag_data(position: Vector2):
    var vControl = Control.new()
    var vData    = {}
    var vTexture = TextureRect.new()
    
    vTexture.expand    = true
    vTexture.texture   = texture_disabled
    vTexture.rect_size = Vector2(320, 400)
    
    vControl.add_child(vTexture)
    vTexture.rect_position = -0.5 * vTexture.rect_size
    
    set_drag_preview(vTexture)
    
    return vData
```

[image: Hierarchy]

Code above is attached to Party_1. texture_disabled does have a texture set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you had the code in `get_drag_data` looking like this:

```
func get_drag_data(_position: Vector2):
    var vTexture = TextureRect.new()
    vTexture.expand    = true
    vTexture.texture   = texture_disabled
    vTexture.rect_size = Vector2(320, 400)
    set_drag_preview(vTexture)
    return {}
```

However, that would place the `TextureRect` top-left corner at the cursor position.

You want to offset the position of the `TextureRect` so it is centered at the cursor position. To do that, you create another `Control`, add the `TextureRect` as a child to it… And pass the `TextureRect` anyway? No, that does not work, you need to pass the new `Control`:

```
func get_drag_data(_position: Vector2):
    var vTexture = TextureRect.new()
    vTexture.expand    = true
    vTexture.texture   = texture_disabled
    vTexture.rect_size = Vector2(320, 400)

    var vControl = Control.new()
    vControl.add_child(vTexture)
    vTexture.rect_position = -0.5 * vTexture.rect_size

    set_drag_preview(vControl)
    return {}
```

Please notice I'm giving `vControl` to `set_drag_preview`, not `vTexture`.

---

You cannot give to `set_drag_preview` a `Control` that has a parent. In fact, if you tried you would get an error in the Output console saying:

```
_gui_set_drag_preview: Condition "p_control->get_parent() != nullptr" is true.
```

Or

```
_gui_set_drag_preview: Condition "p_control->is_inside_tree()" is true.
```